# Parse JSON array of hashes into jQuery tokenInput

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-tokeninput

I have jQuery token input implemented for tagging purposes where a user can search for a tag or create a new one thanks to railscasts [ep#382](http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging) & [ep#258](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised). Data comes from the `tags.json` url which is the index action of the tags controller. The data from tags.json looks like so:

```
[
  {
    "created_at":"2013-06-21T16:30:19Z",
    "explanation":"hitting the hosel of the club",
    "id":8,
    "name":"shank",
    "updated_at":"2013-06-21T16:30:19Z",
    "updated_by":"andy"
  },
  {
    "created_at":"2013-06-22T17:40:37Z",
    "explanation":"hitting the ground before the ball",
    "id":12,
    "name":"chunk",
    "updated_at":"2013-06-22T17:40:37Z",
    "updated_by":"andy"
  }
]
```

My tags have a name as well as an explanation so I would like to include them in the results list like the **Token and Results Formatting** demo here http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html#formatting.

The code below (number of entries omitted for brevity) is from the jQuery tokenInput **Token and Results Formatting** demo.

Instead of having "name": "Shank" manually entered here as well as the other omitted entries, how can I extract the name and explanation from tags.json hash and use them in the same was as the results formatter line, e.g. item.name & item.explanation?

tags.js

```
jQuery(function() {
var question = $('#question_tag_tokens')
  return question.tokenInput([{
       "name": "Shank",
       "explanation": "hitting the hosel of the club"
   }
 ], {
    propertyToSearch: ["name"],
    resultsFormatter: function(item){ return "<li>" + "<div class='tag' style='display:inline;color:#fff;'>" + item.name + "</div>" + " " + item.explanation + "</li>" },
    prePopulate: question.data('preload')
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you asking how to load that json from rails in your javascript?  The example shows that you would pass the whole array into your `tokenInput` call.

Comment: oh ok, its much simpler than i thought, you can access the item.explanation from token inputs('tags.json') PUt that in an answer @joeshmo and ill gladly accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source for the example you referred to goes like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#demo-input-local-custom-formatters").tokenInput(
         [{
             "first_name": "Arthur",
             "last_name": "Godfrey",
             "email": "arthur_godfrey@nccu.edu",
             "url": "https://si0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_2_normal.png"
         },
         {
             "first_name": "Adam",
             "last_name": "Johnson",
             "email": "wravo@yahoo.com",
             "url": "https://si0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_2_normal.png"
         },
         ...

         ], 
         {
             propertyToSearch: "first_name",
             resultsFormatter: function(item){ ... },
             tokenFormatter: function(item) { ... }
         });
});
```

`tokenInput` seems to take an array of objects.  Once you load the json with ajax, you just pass it in and tell it what field to search on and some callbacks to format the results.